# Custom share button on a wordpress site - doesn't open a new window correctly

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been searching the web for ways to make a custom share button for my wordpress site posts.

1 - So I have my own image "share" file. 
2 - Pasted this code in the  tag:

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'myNumber',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


      $('.btnShare').click(function(){
        elem = $(this);
        postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));

        return false;
        });
    </script>
```

3 - on my single.php page I added this line:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook." target="_blank">SHARE</a>
```

The problem is that it opens a normal window and not the regular small pop-up window that facebook usually has.

Can someone help me fix this? 
If you have any good tutorials how to add a custom Facebook button without any trouble I'll be happy to start all over. 
(no wordpress plugins pls..)

TNX, 
Hatzil666.

Comment: For custom window you have to use `<a href="#" onclick="window.open(link,target,[options]);"` in the options you have to specify the width, height, position etc. [Just an Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: still doesn't work 
`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook." onclick=window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100")>SHARE</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook." onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwin', 'width=200, height=100'); return false;" >SHARE</a>
```

Modify the width, height, scrollbars etc within the options

Comment: ^ 
Didn't work.. 
I tried `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook." onclick="window.open(this.href, "newwin", "width=200, height=100")">SHARE</a>`too. 
doesn't change the way it works. Still opens a big page and now even a new page..

Comment: Please take a look of the above code in action at this ***>>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CuvE/1/)<<***